# Batch checking for correct ip-range

Tags: batch-file

IM looking for a better solution. checking the computer for if the computer is online and if its in the correct network. The reason for this is that the rest of the batch need network, and is printing a log to a lan printer. 
Se my code for what i use today.

```
@ECHO off
COLOR f8
TITLE WLAN CHECK
REM Maskin pinger www.vg.no
:wlancheck
ping www.vg.no>nul
if errorlevel 1 goto nonet
if errorlevel 0 goto gotnet

:nonet 
color cf
echo [WLAN CHECK][:::::::::FAILED!::::::::]
echo THE COMPUTER HAS NO INTERNET CONNECTION
ECHO            CONNECT NOW!!!
timeout /t 15
Goto wlancheck
:gotnet
color cf
```

I use the same for ping my printer.

The best solution for me is if there was a way " if connected to snid blablabla" goto continue
echo not connected please retry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ipconfig` can be used:

```
ipconfig | find /i "MY_WLAN_CONNECTION_NAME" >nul && goto continue || echo not connected
```

Replace `MY_WLAN_CONNECTION_NAME` with your connection name as seen in the output of `ipconfig` when the connection is established.

Comment: Just to be clear i understand the code right. "do ipconfig and search in output for "my_wlan_connection" do not show output and goto menu continue, if code does not complete output "not connected" what does he | between ipconfig and find mean?

Comment: `command_sequence && success_action || fail_action` executes the command sequence and if the errorlevel is 0 (success) does `success_action` otherwise proceeds with `fail_action`. Basically `&&` is a notation of logical AND, `||` is logical `OR` widely used in programming languages.